# Why doesn't $0! = 1$ in the context of this general term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

Is my instructor wrong to say that $\left\{0,\frac{1!}{4},\frac{2!}{9},\frac{3!}{16},\dots\right\} = \left\{\frac{(n-1)!}{n^2}\right\}$?

My understanding is that at $n=1$, $\frac{(n-1)!}{n^2}$ should equal $1$, not $0$.

Comment: Should that be $\frac{3!}{16}$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't that $0!=1$, the problem is that the first term in the sequence doesn't match the pattern of the other terms. The sequence whose $n^{\text{th}}$ term is $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n^2}$ looks like
$$1,\ \dfrac{1}{4},\ \dfrac{2}{9},\ \dfrac{6}{16},\ \dots$$
whereas your sequence starts with $0$, not $1$.

Comment: So the instructor was wrong if he claimed that the general term was $\frac{(n-1)!}{n^2}$. And of course also for using curly braces here ;)

Comment: That was what I thought, so I'm glad it's not just me.